# move some commits to a new branch in Hg

Tags: mercurial, branch

My repo is currently as follows:

```
O 7: default
|
O 6: default
|
|  O 5: default
|  |
|  O 4: default
|  |
|  O 3: default
| /
O 2: default
|
O 1: default
```

I would like to move 6 and  7 to a new branch, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [rebase extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) for this.  It needs to be enabled but that link has the information on how to do it.

The commands would be:

```
hg update 2
hg branch newbranch
hg commit -m "Creating new branch"
hg rebase -s 6 -d 8
```

This creates the new branch, commits it (which would create revision 8 in your example) and then moves revision 6 and its descendants onto the new branch.  Obviously, you'd need to look up the actual revision numbers for your repository.

You could also do it with the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) but I think that rebase is easier to use in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you define the term "branch". If you're talking about [named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches) then Steve Kaye's answer is fine.

If you're talking about a branch like 5 & 6 are on a branch in your diagram, then you don't need to do anything. 6 & 7 are already on their own branch. You can leave them alone, and move back to revision 2 to continue work there.

```
hg update 2
<continue work>
hg commit -m "New Stuff"
```

That will leave you with a graph like this:

```
o 8: default
|  
|  O 7: default
|  |
|  O 6: default
|  |
|  |  O 5: default
|  |  |
|  |  O 4: default
|  |  |
|  |  O 3: default
 \ | /
   O 2: default
   |
   O 1: default
```

If you want to assign a name to each of those tips, take a look at [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks).

```
hg bookmark -r 8 stable
hg bookmark -r 7 experimental-stuff
hg bookmark -r 5 some-feature
```

... and then you can change between them by name.