# How should I handle a pull request in BitBucket which requires some tweaks?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, open-source, branching-and-merging

Someone has sent me a pull request on BitBucket. The change in question is submitted on the default branch. Before I merge it in, I'd like to make a couple of tweaks, but more importantly, I'd like to publish a preview build of this change, for the community to evaluate it and see if they're happy.

*Ideally* I would like to pull the change into the main repo, but *put it on a branch*. Make a couple of tweaks. Tag it like I would any other build, and publish. However, it doesn't seem like this is possible: if I understand correctly, the branch is "baked in" and I can't pull the change onto a different branch. Is this correct?

If so, what can I do instead? I could pull and then merge the second head into oblivion, while also creating a branch off the change I pulled. Or I could do the work on a fork, but this would mean that there will be no tag associated with this build in the main repo. Or should I do something else altogether?

P.S. The change itself is high quality and this is *not* about asking the original author to improve it.

Comment: Would it be possible to pull the changes into 'default', but leave them unmerged, bookmarking the new head to give it a label. That way you don't have the problems associated with rebasing. I'm not 100% if BitBucket supports bookmarks though.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the Bitbucket 'accept pull request' just pull the changes into your local repo. You can use rebase to move the commit (or set of commits) on to a named branch. Then just push the changes you main bitbucket repo. (and possible reject the bibucket pull request with a comment saying the changes have been push to the main repo)

For example:

if you repo is:
bitbucket/ProjectA/MainRepoForProjectA

and the pullrequest is from: 
bitbucket/someuser/MainRepoForProjectA

1. pull from bitbucket/someuser/MainRepoMainRepoForProjectA
2. rebase to newly pulled commits to named branch.
3. Make any extra changes you want to make.
4. push to bitbucket/ProjectA/MainRepoMainRepoForProjectA

Note:
If you haven't used rebase before then:

1. Enable it in TortoiseHg File -> Settings -> Extensions
2. Update to the head of branch you want to move the the changes too.
3. Right click on the base of the changes you to move -> Modify History -> Rebase

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful:

http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2014/03/31/test-a-pull-merge-request-before-accepting-on-bitbucket/

Basically, the link says to do the following:

- git fetch https://bitbucket.org/myrepository/master somename
- git checkout FETCH_HEAD
- inspect code and test to heart's content.
- (if code is accepted), git checkout master
- git merge FETCH_HEAD
- git push

Answer (score 2):

What accepting a pull request does is described in the [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Working+with+pull+requests); it'll try to merge, and you'll get to solve conflicts. The docs do mention you can set the target branch when creating the pull request. But since your branch didn't exist yet, your contributor couldn't pick it.

So you'll have to pull to your local machine and [move some commits to a new branch in Hg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14159849/383793) then push to your bitbucket.

Do read the rebase [docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) because changing history will have consequences for the validity of your contributors repo, he'll have to fork again to be in sync with you again. This can become cumbersome if he already has some more high quality code ready for you.

Answer (score 0):

One may pull the code for the pull request as:

```
git fetch origin refs/pull-requests/$PR_NO/from:$LOCAL_BRANCH
```